# Copied files without git repo, how to bring changes into master

Tags: git

Instead of cloning my repository on my deployment server, I uploaded the files using FTP. However, I forgot to upload the .git portion and have made changes that I now want to merge into master as they are part of the deployment branch. But there is no git repository there.

What I'd like to do, is commit the deployment changes to my existing remote. But I'm not sure how I would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload the `.git` files; they will contain a record of what the status was before, and you'll be able to run `git status` to find out what's different.

Remember to copy any other `.hidden` files as well. Especially `.gitignore`, if you have one.